Blocking access to a JS file on both local and stage environments
I want to block requests (e.g., https://test.com/test/Test/TestScript.js) from being served. The code added to the web.config file successfully blocks this JavaScript file being returned locally but does not have the same effect on the stage environment. Can you suggest improvements or modifications to ensure this block works in both local and staging environments?
  <location path="Test/TestScript.js">
      <system.web>
          <authorization>
              <deny users="*" />
          </authorization>
      </system.web>
  </location>


How does your Staging environment differ from Local and Production? Does it happen in Prod too? Also, using web.config's <system.web><authorization> rules won't help you if you're using IIS' URL-rewriting or not using WebForms's auth suite.

I also use IIS to start up my application locally so it should work the same on stage

…that doesn’t answer my question.
